# Need assistance with MySQL query into array and output into an echo

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

I need some PHP coding assistance in building an echo to display the results of a database query...(list friends of the logged-in user?) I have the majority of it built, but I don't know how to echo the results data and link it to his/her profile? Any help would be greatly appreciated...maybe a code snippet of how to write it out?

Here is my code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    array_push($my_friends, $row["user2"]);
    array_push($my_friends, $row["user1"]);
}
//remove your id from array
$my_friends = array_diff($my_friends, array($u));
//reset the key values
$my_friends = array_values($my_friends);
mysqli_free_result($query);
} else {
    echo "You have no friends.";
}

// Build My friends From Results
     ****this is where I need help with*****

if (array_key_exists('0', $my_friends)){
    $sql = "SELECT user1, user2 
    FROM friends 
    WHERE (user1='$u' OR user2='$u')
    AND accepted='1'";      
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$my_friends = "<a href='user.php?u=".$result."'>". $row['avatar']. '&nbsp'. $row['firstname']. '&nbsp' .$row['lastname'] ."</a>"; }
}
?>

Here is my html code:
<?php
echo "<li>$my_friends</li>"; 
  ?>
```

Comment: How exactly do you want the `links` to look like on the HTML page?

Comment: I'm putting them into a unordered listview page that auto-divides alphabetically by last name, so I want it to basically expand the <li> inside the <ul> and then each item will link back to that user's profile which is user.php?u="userid""

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `$result` variable in the html link. Replace it with `$row['id']` or the row attribute you use as GET parameter to see a user's detailed page